# 2 Dimensional ArrayList not Printing Properly

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a function to print a mase, which is stored in a `2 Dimensional ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. However, the function instead prints out a large portion of blank space. I am attempting to first iterate through each `ArrayList<String>` and then iterate through each `String` element inside the nested `ArrayList<String>`s. I am creating the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` from reading a file.

Here is the file:

```
XXXXXXXXSOOOOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXOOOOOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXOXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXEXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here is where I create it:

```
String fileName = "maze.txt";
String line = null;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// Setup FileReader, BufferedReader, and LineReader
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

// Get all the lines inside the maze file
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        lineList.add(line.substring(i, i));
    }

    lines.add(lineList);                
}
```

Here is my function:

```
public static void printMase(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines)
{
    for (ArrayList<String> row: lines)
    {
        for (String elem: row)
        {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add example input and expected output?

Comment: I'd guess that most of the inner ArrayLists are actually empty.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I added the input and expected output.

Comment: Just a comment, using a two dimensional arraylist of strings seems like a pretty inefficient way to store a Snake game state if that's really what you are doing here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just some minor mistakes in your code.  Make the following changes.

```
// This is adding a blank space
lineList.add(line.substring(i, i));
```

To

```
// This will add a single character
lineList.add(line.substring(i, i+1));
```

and modify `printMase(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines)`

```
public static void printMase(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines)
{
    for (ArrayList<String> row: lines)
    {
        for (String elem: row)
        {
            // Using print so each character is on the same line
            System.out.print(elem);
        }
        // Now use println to end the line
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Full code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = "maze.txt";
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    // Setup FileReader, BufferedReader, and LineReader
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    // Get all the lines inside the maze file
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            // Adds a single character
            lineList.add(line.substring(i, i+1));
        }

        lines.add(lineList);
    }

    printMase(lines);
}

public static void printMase(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines)
{
    for (ArrayList<String> row: lines)
    {
        for (String elem: row)
        {
            // Using print so each character is on the same line
            System.out.print(elem);
        }
        // Now use println to end the line
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
XXXXXXXXSOOOOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXX
XXXXXXXOOOOOXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXOXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXEXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops, I realized that I was adding *blank space during initialization*. I updated my code such that it was adding the actual characters:

```
String fileName = "maze.txt";
String line = null;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// Setup FileReader, BufferedReader, and LineReader
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        lineList.add(Character.toString(line.charAt(i)));
    }

    lines.add(lineList);                
}
```